# Unlimited Page Sitemap Link

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, sitemap

I am trying to display all the product links (7000+) of woocommerce, but I get a blank result when doing so. When I set `'posts_per_page'` to 2000, it returns a result. More than 2000 returns a blank page

```
<?php if ( is_woocommerce_activated() ): ?>

                <h3><?php _e( 'Product Categories', 'woothemes' ) ?></h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=product_cat&pad_counts=1&title_li=' ); ?>
                </ul>

                <h3><?php _e( 'Products', 'woothemes' ); ?></h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page' => -1 );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please enable [`WP_DEBUG` mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and add error messages that come up to your question.

Comment: That's another problem, there is no error even debug is enabled

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably exceeding the maximum execution time when trying to retrieve **7000** posts/products, or specifically more than 2000 posts/products.

To be quite honest with you, 7000 posts/products (or even just a list of posts/products) all packed in one single page is not only going to drive you crazy, but anyone visiting your site. I can imagine how long does 2000 posts/products take to load if just a little more exceeds the maximum execution time, 7000 is more than 3 times more.

If I was a new prospective client, you would have lost my business simply by just frustrating me when a extremely long page load.

Comment: any alternative solution, how about creating a pagination for the 7000+ line e.g. each pagination will have 1000 products though i think that would beat the purpose of a sitemap

Comment: I've been thinking about an alternative, but can't seem to come up with one.

Comment: thanks really appreciate maybe i should just create a php code calling all the links for loop and use iframe just not sure how to do that

Comment: Have you tried [`wp_get_archives('type=alpha');`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Comment: yes i did alreadu